# How do I figure out if my temporary folder is overloading? Run-time error '6': Overflow

Tags: excel, vba, theory

I have a macro that threw

> Run-time error '6':
> Overflow

[image: Run-time error '6' screenshot]

I don't think there's anything wrong with the code, I think the nature of the task takes too long, therefore overloading the temp folder. Per [TechWalla](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-fix-runtime-error-6-overflow) (***emphasis*** mine):

> The Runtime Error 6 occurs in the Visual Basic program. It is an overflow issue that can occur when the Visual Basic program attempts to store ***too much data in the temporary folders area***. Runtime files help Windows translate a program's language into Windows language so the program runs faster. You can get the Runtime Error 6 message for several reasons. One reason is that you are using a backslash instead of a forward slash in one of your calculations. Other reasons include ***an overloaded temporary folder***, outdated software or a registry error.

(**Caveat:** I haven't seen this explanation elsewhere and can't vouch for how reliable Techwalla is.)

Is there a way to determine if this is the case? I outline below why I think this is what's causing the error, which might help, but doesn't change the question. **If this is the case, is there a way to find out? And if so, is there a way to prevent it?**

(I'll be running it again tonight now that I've used a registry cleaner that found 1GB, though I don't know how much was from Excel. For reference, my C: drive has 180GB free.)

The description above specifically mentions Visual Basic, which is not VBA. I'm keeping it in as I know Excel uses/creates temporary files, and has memory limits, which is ultimately what I'm curious about.

```vb
Sub getCBU()

Dim rowCount As Long, newRow(1 To 17) As Variant, compareRow(1 To 17) As Variant, nextFile As String, s As Long
Dim location As String, lastRow As Long, match As Boolean, startTime As Double, secondsElapsed As String

location = "C:\Users\swallin\Documents\CBU History\"
nextFile = Dir(location & "CBU*")
rowCount = 2

startTime = Timer

Do While nextFile <> ""
    
    Workbooks.Open (location & nextFile)
    lastRow = Workbooks(nextFile).Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For s = 18 To lastRow
    
        match = True
        
        For x = 1 To 17
            newRow(x) = Workbooks(nextFile).Worksheets(1).Cells(s, x)
        Next x
        
        For y = 2 To rowCount
        
            If Val(newRow(11)) = Val(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(y, 11)) Then
                
                For j = 1 To 17
                    compareRow(j) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(y, j).Value
                Next j
                
                For v = 1 To 17
                    If Val(compareRow(v)) <> Val(newRow(v)) Then
                        match = False
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        match = True
                    End If
                Next v
            
                If match = True Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                
            Else
                match = False
            End If
        
        Next y
        
        y = 2
        
        If match = False Then
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
            For t = 1 To 17
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rowCount, t) = newRow(t)
            Next t
        End If
    
    Next s
    
    s = 18
    
    Workbooks(nextFile).Close
    
    nextFile = Dir()

Loop

secondsElapsed = Format((Timer - startTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = secondsElapsed

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line does throw the overload error?

Comment: Is always a good idea to avoid looping over the sheet itself, and way faster if you add that data in an array and loop over the array instead. The less you interact with the spreadsheet, the better.

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve? Because it seems that you are looking for matches and then doing something else, which is fairly easy and fast to do with arrays and dictionaries. Thought I can't see anything wrong here, maybe some value is an error or something of the sort.

Comment: Actually I think any of your variables produces the overflow. See [Overflow (Error 6)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/overflow-error-6) • Also there are not declared variables in your code like `j`. Declare all of them properly. I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: Also, check your Memory Usage in Task Manager - if this is excessive then A) use `Workbooks.Open location & nextFile, ReadOnly:=True` to prevent Excel creating temporary files and B) Consider saving your workbook periodically to "discard" unsaved changes from memory

Comment: Note that the description of Error 6 you included is for **Visual Basic** and not for **VBA** (see the link in my comment above which is the description for VBA). Also we cannot help without seeing your code (see [ask]) since the code is producing that error and needs to be fixed/changed.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Even if I'm specifically asking about the theory or definitions/limitations? This is something I'm curious about and don't have the technical education nor can I find the answer elsewhere online.

Comment: Again the description of the error that you posted is NOT for VBA. It is the wrong description. Therefore there is no theory about this in VBA. You are up the wrong tree. You have to search for the error in your code. Please show your code and tell in which line you get the error.

Comment: Apologies, I missed what you meant.

Comment: Also, there was no line that was highlighted. There was no option to debug. It just kicked out. That was it.

Comment: @sethW Then go through the code step by step using F8. So you will see which line finally throws the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193777/discussion-between-sethw-and-p).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the writing back to the sheet part (i would still allocate the values to an array and write it back all together, but that depends on what you have in the sheet already, plus whatever `newRow()` does), but can you give this a try and see if there is any improvement in speed?

```
Sub getCBU()

Dim rowCount As Long, newRow(1 To 17) As Variant, compareRow(1 To 17) As Variant, nextFile As String
Dim location As String, lastRow As Long, match As Boolean, startTime As Double, secondsElapsed As String

Dim arrData, arrOutput()
Dim arrTemp(): ReDim arrOutput(1 To 17, 1 To 1)
Dim R As Long, C As Long

location = "C:\Users\swallin\Documents\CBU History\"
nextFile = Dir(location & "CBU*")
rowCount = 2

startTime = Timer

Do While nextFile <> ""

    Workbooks.Open (location & nextFile)
    lastRow = Workbooks(nextFile).Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    With Workbooks(nextFile).Worksheets(1)
        arrData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 17))
    End With

    For s = 18 To lastRow

        match = True

        For X = 1 To 17
            newRow(X) = arrData(s, X)
        Next X

        For y = 2 To rowCount

            If Val(newRow(11)) = Val(arrData(y, 11)) Then

                For j = 1 To 17
                    compareRow(j) = arrData(y, j).Value
                Next j

                For v = 1 To 17
                    If Val(compareRow(v)) <> Val(newRow(v)) Then
                        match = False
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        match = True
                    End If
                Next v

                If match = True Then
                    Exit For
                End If

            Else
                match = False
            End If

        Next y

        y = 2

        If match = False Then
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrTemp(1 To 17, 1 To rowCount)
            For t = 1 To 17
                arrTemp(t, rowCount) = newRow(t)
            Next t
        End If

    Next s

    s = 18

    Workbooks(nextFile).Close

    nextFile = Dir()

Loop

    'Transpose the array
    ReDim arrOutput(1 To UBound(arrTemp, 2), 1 To UBound(arrTemp))
    For C = LBound(arrTemp) To UBound(arrTemp)
        For R = LBound(arrTemp, 2) To UBound(arrTemp, 2)
            arrOutput(R, C) = arrTemp(C, R)
        Next R
    Next C

    'Allocate back to the spreadsheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(UBound(arrOutput) + 1, 17)) = arrOutput
    End With


secondsElapsed = Format((Timer - startTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = secondsElapsed

End Sub
```

PS: As others suggested, is a good idea to use `Option Explicit`, and eventually to step through to code and see if everything is working as intended.

As for the Overflow issue...  stepping through code would/should resolve that as well eventually. See [Overflow (Error 6)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/overflow-error-6) for more info.

**EDIT:** I've added further management to holding the values in an array, and writing back to the spreadsheet.

Comment: So just for my own understanding, when rows of data are added to an array in the form of a range, it's automatically entered as a 2-dimensional array, dividing them by rows? And a variant array will be large enough to hold 50k rows of data with 17 columns each? Not doubting you, just had no idea.

Comment: Also, the `newRow()` array was simply holding each new line from the opened file so that it could be compared with what had already been entered in the main file. 1. Read the next row into `newRow()` 2. Run through what has already been logged 3. Toss if already logged. 4. Add to main file if unique. And I'm writing to the main file each time because there might ultimately be up to a few hundred thousand rows of data, and didn't want to run the chance of overflowing an array holding it all.

Comment: That's correct, allocating a range to a variant array will automatically be entered as a 2d array (starting at 1!). As far as I can tell, there is no reason why the array shouldn't be able to hold 50k/17, or hundreds of thousands. Though I've never needed at such sizes, I've just randomly populated a sheet up to 1kk, over the 17 columns and it loads in the array just fine. Loading and writing it back to a second sheet took in total approx 35 seconds, with only 5 seconds at 500k/17 for same process.

Comment: If your array gets to a crazy size and starts actiging weird, you might want to decide in your code to dump it in the spreadsheet at every 200k rows or so. i.e.: `If ubound(arrOutput) > 200k then....`. Or do so for every workbook at least (collect rows to array), and not for every row to be written.

Comment: I've added further management to holding the values in an array, and writing back to the spreadsheet... As you can probably notice I've kept the changes to your code to a minimum, so should be relatively easy to spot what has changed, and improve upon as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

This opens a new instance for each file and closes it afterwards. Give it a try (I could not test it). This includes all the suggestions I made in the chat.

```
Option Explicit

Sub getCBU()
    Dim location As String
    location = "C:\Users\swallin\Documents\CBU History\"

    Dim nextFile As String
    nextFile = Dir(location & "CBU*")

    Dim rowCount As Long
    rowCount = 2

    Dim startTime As Double
    startTime = Timer


    Dim newRow(1 To 17) As Variant, compareRow(1 To 17) As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long, match As Boolean

    Dim s As Long, x As Long, y As Long, j As Long, v As Long, t As Long

    Dim objExcel As Object, ActWb As Workbook


    Do While nextFile <> ""
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'new excel instance
        Set ActWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=location & nextFile, ReadOnly:=True)

        lastRow = ActWb.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For s = 18 To lastRow
            match = True

            For x = 1 To 17
                newRow(x) = ActWb.Worksheets(1).Cells(s, x)
            Next x

            For y = 2 To rowCount
                If Val(newRow(11)) = Val(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(y, 11)) Then
                    For j = 1 To 17
                        compareRow(j) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(y, j).Value
                    Next j

                    For v = 1 To 17
                        If Val(compareRow(v)) <> Val(newRow(v)) Then
                            match = False
                            Exit For
                        Else
                            match = True
                        End If
                    Next v

                    If match = True Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Else
                    match = False
                End If
            Next y

            y = 2

            If match = False Then
                rowCount = rowCount + 1
                For t = 1 To 17
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rowCount, t) = newRow(t)
                Next t
            End If
        Next s

        s = 18

        ActWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        objExcel.Quit 'close excel instance
        Set objExcel = Nothing 'free variable

        nextFile = Dir()
    Loop

    Dim secondsElapsed As String
    secondsElapsed = Format$((Timer - startTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = secondsElapsed
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revamp of your code that should be quicker and more memory friendly. (updated to be able to handle any number of results).

```
Sub getCBU()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim wsTime As Worksheet
    Dim hUnqVals As Object
    Dim hUnqRows As Object
    Dim aHeaders() As Variant
    Dim aCompare() As Variant
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim aStartingData() As Variant
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sDelim As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim lMaxResults As Long
    Dim lCompareStartRow As Long
    Dim lValCompareCol As Long
    Dim ixCompare As Long
    Dim ixResult As Long
    Dim ixCol As Long
    Dim dTimer As Double

    dTimer = Timer

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsTime = wb.Worksheets(2)
    Set hUnqRows = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set hUnqVals = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    sDelim = "|"
    lMaxResults = 100000
    lCompareStartRow = 18
    lValCompareCol = 11

    sFolder = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Documents\CBU History\"    'Be sure to including ending \
    sFile = Dir(sFolder & "CBU*.xlsx")

    With wsDest.Range("A2:Q" & wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, lValCompareCol).End(xlUp).Row)
        If .Row > 1 Then
            aHeaders = .Offset(-1).Resize(1).Value
            aStartingData = .Value
            ReDim aResults(1 To lMaxResults, 1 To .Columns.Count)
            For ixResult = 1 To UBound(aStartingData, 1)
                For ixCol = 1 To UBound(aStartingData, 2)
                    sTemp = sTemp & sDelim & aStartingData(ixResult, ixCol)
                Next ixCol
                If Not hUnqRows.Exists(sTemp) Then hUnqRows.Add sTemp, sTemp
                If Not hUnqVals.Exists(aStartingData(ixResult, lValCompareCol)) Then hUnqVals.Add aStartingData(ixResult, lValCompareCol), aStartingData(ixResult, lValCompareCol)
                sTemp = vbNullString
            Next ixResult
            Erase aStartingData
        Else
            'No data to compare against, so no data can be added, exit macro
            MsgBox "No data found in [" & wsDest.Name & "]" & Chr(10) & "Exiting Macro.", , "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    ixResult = 0
    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & sFile & "..."
        With Workbooks.Open(sFolder & sFile, , True).Worksheets(1)
            With .Range("A" & lCompareStartRow & ":Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, lValCompareCol).End(xlUp).Row)
                If .Row >= lCompareStartRow Then
                    aCompare = .Value
                    For ixCompare = 1 To UBound(aCompare, 1)
                        If hUnqVals.Exists(aCompare(ixCompare, lValCompareCol)) Then
                            For ixCol = 1 To UBound(aCompare, 2)
                                sTemp = sTemp & sDelim & aCompare(ixCompare, ixCol)
                            Next ixCol
                            If Not hUnqRows.Exists(sTemp) Then
                                hUnqRows.Add sTemp, sTemp
                                ixResult = ixResult + 1
                                For ixCol = 1 To UBound(aCompare, 2)
                                    aResults(ixResult, ixCol) = aCompare(ixCompare, ixCol)
                                Next ixCol
                                If ixResult = lMaxResults Then OutputResults wsDest, aResults, ixResult, aHeaders
                            End If
                            sTemp = vbNullString
                        End If
                    Next ixCompare
                    Erase aCompare
                End If
            End With
            .Parent.Close False
        End With
        sFile = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.StatusBar = vbNullString
    If ixResult > 0 Then OutputResults wsDest, aResults, ixResult, aHeaders
    wsTime.Range("A1").Value = Format((Timer - dTimer) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub

Sub OutputResults(ByRef arg_ws As Worksheet, ByRef arg_aResults As Variant, ByRef arg_ixResult As Long, ByVal arg_aHeaders As Variant)

    Static wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim lMaxRows As Long
    Dim lMaxCols As Long

    If wsDest Is Nothing Then Set wsDest = arg_ws
    lMaxRows = UBound(arg_aResults, 1)
    lMaxCols = UBound(arg_aResults, 2)

    Set rDest = wsDest.Range("A1").Resize(, lMaxCols).EntireColumn.Find("*", wsDest.Range("A1"), xlValues, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
    If rDest Is Nothing Then Set rDest = wsDest.Range("A2") Else Set rDest = wsDest.Cells(rDest.Row, "A")

    If rDest.Row + 1 + arg_ixResult > wsDest.Rows.Count Then
        Set wsDest = wsDest.Parent.Worksheets.Add(After:=wsDest)
        With wsDest.Range("A1").Resize(, lMaxCols)
            .Value = arg_aHeaders
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
        Set rDest = wsDest.Range("A2")
    End If

    rDest.Resize(arg_ixResult, lMaxCols).Value = arg_aResults

    Erase arg_aResults
    ReDim arg_aResults(1 To lMaxRows, 1 To lMaxCols)

End Sub
```